# How to change file names with "rename" command in any depth?

Tags: bash, file-rename

I want to rename files in any depth with help of "rename" command:

```
rename 's/.css/.less/' **/*
```

But I get renamed files only in folders of second level:

```
./style.css
./dir/style.less
./dir/dir/style.css
./dir/dir/dir/style.css
```

Does anybody know why?

(Debian 7, GNU bash, version 4.2.37)

Comment: did you wanna a rename to work on all the subdirectories?

Comment: I've just done it using find + rename, but it's interesting why rename itself doesn't work.

Comment: I would be VERY careful with using the command "rename", as I have found it to be very different on different machines.   There a re many versions of "rename", all for renaming multiple files, but they do so in different ways with different input arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the below find command on the root directory.

```
$ find . -name "*.css" -type f -exec rename 's/\.css$/.less/' {} \;
```

OR

```
$ shopt -s globstar; rename 's/\.css$/.less/' **/*
```

From "man bash":

> globstar
>
> If  set,  the  pattern  ** used in a pathname expansion context will
>   match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If
>   the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories
>   match.

To get your current value of "globstar":

```
$ shopt globstar
```

To set on:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
```

To set off:

```
$ shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: find works OK. But the question is why \*\*/\* in "rename" command doesn't work properly?

Comment: I've just found out that ** works in any depth if "globstar" is set.

Comment: Did you "shopt -s globstar" before "rename"?

Comment: yep, you missed the last `/` after less and also you need to put end of the line anchor `$`. And also you need to escape the dot...